# "WHERE X > ALL SELECT MAX" vs "WHERE X > SELECT MAX"

Tags: sql

I came across multiple queries which use the all quantor for a max subquery:

Is there any difference between

```
SELECT name FROM bbc
 WHERE population > ALL
       (SELECT MAX(population)
          FROM bbc
         WHERE region = 'Europe')
   AND region = 'South Asia'
```

and

```
SELECT name FROM bbc
 WHERE population > 
       (SELECT MAX(population)
          FROM bbc
         WHERE region = 'Europe')
   AND region = 'South Asia'
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SELECT MAX` is an aggregate operation and, therefore, your subquery will select a single row.

Applying `ALL` to a single row will have no effect.

If your subquery returned multiple rows, the non-`ALL` version would result in an error. Also note that when using `ALL`, you could remove the `MAX` from the subquery and you'd get correct results (presumably with the same performance characteristics).