# Why using ALL when I can use MAX

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, operator-keyword

I just found the ALL comparison operator. I see some examples like

```
select ProductId, Price
from tbl1 
where Price > ALL (select Price from tbl2)
```

When I say `a_value is > All (some_other_values)`, I always can say `a_value > MAX(some_other-values)`

so above query is equal to

```
select ProductId, Price
from tbl1 
where Price > (select Max(Price) from tbl2)
```

so why SQL Server provided ALL operator?

Comment: Well, what if you wanted to know all products that are priced higher than the *average* price in some other table? How would you do `WHERE price > ALL (SELECT AVG(price) FROM dbo.Products GROUP BY Category)`? You can't say `WHERE price > (SELECT MAX(AVG(price)) FROM dbo.Products)`. Now, that said, I am not a fan at all of `ANY`,`SOME`, or `ALL`, and like `RIGHT JOIN`, would strive to re-write the query to avoid them. But they are in the standard, and they do serve purposes other than `> max()`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, look like it is a neat shortcut. is there any practical usage that we can't do in any other way?

Comment: I don't know that I've ever thought about it that way, but no, I don't think I can envision any query that uses `ALL` that I couldn't re-write to not use it.

Comment: This may be helpful ["WHERE X > ALL SELECT MAX" vs "WHERE X > SELECT MAX"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27096405/where-x-all-select-max-vs-where-x-select-max)

Comment: This question will spawn opinions. The only fact here is that ALL/ANY are defined by the ANSI SQL standard and that the SQL Server developer team decided to implement that part of the standard.

Comment: @Aditya, If you are asking me, I say nothing is wrong with our answer, but my intention was to get scenarios and examples that ALL will have benefits that MAX doesn't. Something like what Aaron Bertrand mentioned. Thank you anyway for your time.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178543.aspx) for ALL operator (SQL Server starting with 2008), **it compares a scalar value with a single-column set of values.**

```
scalar_expression { = | <> | != | > | >= | !> | < | <= | !< } ALL ( subquery )
```

**For example:-**

**`>ALL`** means greater than every value, means greater than the maximum value.

So **`>ALL (1, 2, 3)`** means greater than 3.

Similarly the comparison operator can be changed here, & **`< ALL (1, 2, 3)`** means less than 1.

The **`ALL`** must be preceded by the comparison operators and it also evaluates to **`TRUE`** if the query returns no rows at all.

**For example:-**

The below `OUTER SELECT` query returns all the rows besides the sub-query returning no rows at all.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT 1 AS 'id'
UNION ALL
   SELECT 1 AS 'id'
UNION ALL
   SELECT 2 AS 'id'
UNION ALL
   SELECT 3 AS 'id'
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE id >ALL ( SELECT id FROM CTE WHERE 1 = 0 )
```

So this proves it is having bit different behavior when compared with using the simple MAX in the sub-query.

Comment: @Squirrel, Oop's. Updated the link provided in the answer.  :)